# Create Groups based on the Rank (Bottom and Top) (Redshift)

Tags: sql, case, amazon-redshift, grouping, rank

Hi I have the infos of the first 3 columns and trying to generate the 4th (yellow) one:

The following query doesnt quite work, it generates the top2 but not the bottom2:

```
select t.*,
    case
    when "Sales Rank" >=1 and "Sales Rank" <=2 then 'Top 2'
    when "Sales Rank" >=2 and "Sales Rank" <= max("Sales Rank")-2 then 'Mid'
    when "Sales Rank" <= max("Sales Rank")-2 and "Sales Rank" <= max("Sales Rank") then 'Bottom 2' end as "Rank Group"
from table as t
```

[image: rank]

Comment: You haven't upvoted or accepted ***Any*** answer to ***Any*** of your eight questions.  Please take part in the community by upvoting answers that are helpful and accepting answer that have resolved your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inequality is incorrect, and also you should be using `MAX` as an analytic function over the entire table:

```
SELECT t.*,
    CASE WHEN "Sales Rank" <= 2 THEN 'Top 2'
         WHEN "Sales Rank" <= MAX("Sales Rank") OVER (PARTITION BY Team) -2 THEN 'Mid'
         ELSE 'Bottom 2' END AS "Rank Group"
FROM yourTable t;
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `max("Sales Rank")` you need to be aggregating.

To get the max of a column in a table without aggregation, you need a window function *(as in the `RANK()` function you linked)*.

For example, the following finds the `max("Sales Rank")` across the ***whole*** table.  *(Which may or may not be what you're trying to do, if not, just add a `PARTITION BY xxx` inside the brackets.)*

```
select
  t.*,
  case
    when "Sales Rank" <= 2                            then 'Top 2'
    when "Sales Rank" >= max("Sales Rank") OVER() - 1 then 'Bottom 2'
                                                      else 'Mid'
  end
    as "Rank Group"
from
  table as t
```

Note, I simplified the `CASE` expression, as it will stop 'searching' at the first match.

Answer (score 0):

You are using aggregation functions when you need window functions.  You want the results *per team*, so this looks like:

```
SELECT t.*,
       (CASE WHEN "Sales Rank" <= 2 THEN 'Top 2'
             WHEN "Sales Rank" <= MAX("Sales Rank") OVER (PARTITION BY Team) - 2 THEN 'Mid'
             ELSE 'Bottom 2'
        END) AS Rank_Group
FROM t;
```

Note that you can just use window functions for this purpose.  You don't need the `"Sales Rank"` if you have the actual sales.

Also, fix your column names.  Don't put spaces in the names and don't escape identifiers.